# Black screen after splash in iOS app with Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen, let

I am developing with a small team an hybrid app based on Ionic v1. We have created a new page on it and everything seemed to be OK (at least on Android it is right).

When I compiled for iOS (iPad), a black screen appears after splash but none error message in console while debugging.
After moving between different commits on our repo and recompiling, recompiling ... I could find that the error came when using let to declare a variable in javascript side (controller). It is the first time we used let in the app.
Changing every let for var, the black screen disappeared and everything works perfectly right now.

Anyone knows why? what is wrong between the use of let and iOS in an Ionic framework development?

I would appreciate any suggest,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/4799206). Probably you disrupted one of the rules which causes logical error in your code and that is why you got such a problem. I would recommend you to use the `--prod` command when you build the ionic application, which mostly gets over such weird problems(black screen stuff).